# Schedule cronjob to copy files to different location every week

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I need help to schedule a cron on my server to copy a specific files to different locations every week in a month.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve,

- Week 1 - Copy to location A
- Week 2 - Copy to location B
- Week 3 - Copy to location C
- Week 4 - Copy to location D

The job will then repeat itself every month and I'm planning to use `cp -rf` command to overwrite the old files.

Could someone shed some light on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, basically you could use many declarations in your crontab, one for each week, or a single call to a script that would decide based on the current date.

Follows an example of how to make different cron calls every week:

```
0 0 1  * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/A
0 0 8  * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/B
0 0 15 * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/C
0 0 22 * * cp -fr /path/to/file /path/to/destination/D
```

You may check the expected running datetime here:

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_*_*

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_8_*_*

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_15_*_*

https://crontab.guru/#0_0_22_*_*

Answer (score 0):

The below example will run the cronjobs at **1 AM server time on the 1st, 8th, 15th and 22nd of each month.**

```
0 1 1 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/A
0 1 8 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/B
0 1 15 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/C
0 1 22 * * rsync -avz  /path/to/directory /path/to/destination/D
```

The format for cronjobs is:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

I'd recommend using **rsync** instead of the cp command. If there are a lot of files involved, you can also create a ZIP or Tar before performing the copy.

Thank you!